# Не работает определение нужного юзера для редактирования комментария

Tags: django

решил значит я добавить функционал редактирования и удаления комментариев на своем сайте. Проблема в том что при проверке правильного юзера который создавал пост, исчезают сами кнопки, вне зависимости от автора поста, то-есть даже у самого автора не выводятся кнопки полностью испаряются.

views.py:

```
class AddComment(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'WebPortfolioApp/add_comment.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.project = PortfolioStructure.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['proj_slug'])
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project', kwargs={'proj_slug': self.object.project.slug})

class EditComment(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'WebPortfolioApp/edit_comment.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project', kwargs={'proj_slug': self.object.project.slug})

class DeleteComment(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'WebPortfolioApp/delete_comment.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('project', kwargs={'proj_slug': self.object.project.slug})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', ListProjects.as_view(), name='home'),
path('project/<slug:proj_slug>/', ProjectDetail.as_view(), name='project'),
path('login/', LoginUser.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', logout_user, name='logout'),
path('register/', RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
path('project/<slug:proj_slug>/like', like_view, name='like_project'),
path('project/<slug:proj_slug>/add_comment/', AddComment.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
path('project/comment/<int:pk>/delete', DeleteComment.as_view(), name='delete_comment'),
path('project/comment/<int:pk>/edit', EditComment.as_view(), name='edit_comment'),
```

]

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
project = models.ForeignKey(PortfolioStructure, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
body = models.TextField()
commentator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s - %s' % (self.project.title, self.name)
```

html:

```
            <h2 class="mb-4">Comments...</h2>
        {% if not project.comments.all %}
            No Comments Yet...<div class="mb-4"><a class="link-primary" href="{% url 'add_comment' project.slug %}">Add comment</a></div>

        {% else %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="mb-3"><a class="link-primary" href="{% url 'add_comment' project.slug %}">Add comment</a></div>
        {% else  %}
        <div class="mb-3"><a class="link-primary" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login to add comment</a></div>
        {% endif %}
            {% for comment in project.comments.all %}
            <strong>
                {{ comment.name }} -
                {{ comment.date_added }}
                {% if user == comment.commentator %}
                    <a class="fw-normal link-primary" href="{% url 'edit_comment' comment.pk %}">[edit]</a>
                    <a class="fw-normal link-primary" href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.pk %}">[delete]</a>
                {% endif %}
            </strong>
            <br>
            <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>

            <br>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Под *постом* вы, наверное, имели ввиду *комментарий*. Откуда в шаблоне присутствует переменная ***user***? В любом шаблоне можно обратиться к переменной ***request*** и оттуда уже достать текущего юзера (если он авторизован).

Примерно так:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user == comment.commentator %}
    <a class="fw-normal link-primary" href="{% url 'edit_comment' comment.pk %}">[edit]</a>
    <a class="fw-normal link-primary" href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.pk %}">[delete]</a>
{% endif %}
```